# Framer motion drags off the page

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

Hi I'm trying to build the card stack bellow. As you can see it works perfectly in this sandbox. Though when I try to run it with nextjs, cards start to slip off the page, has anyone found a solution to this? Is there an open issue about it? Any help would be appreciated. NextJS 13

[Working - react app](https://codesandbox.io/s/card-stack-framer-motion-e0v68?file=/public/index.html)

[Not working - nextjs](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bitter-forest-d9whlp?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A7%2C12)